# Is there a way to automatically send an email when website gets published through VS2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, publishing

I was wondering if there is a possibility to automatically send a notification once a new version of ASP.NET MVC site has been published through Visual Studio publish option. Maybe publishing profile can be edited somehow to add custom scripts? I cannot find a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest doing your publishing via TFS Build, that way you can ensure that people aren't publishing code that you don't have in Source Control, and it's easy to setup email notification on Build Completion (using TFS Alerts).

Comment: Good idea. Didn't think of it. I already have a continuous build running, so I guess I would have to add a release build and somehow attach publish procedure to it. How is it done and is it possible to do via hosted TFS?

Comment: It's quite easy to do, and in fact you typically don't even need to edit the build workflow.  This blog post should give you the details you need to set this up in a TFS Build if you've never done it before: http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.ca/2010/11/team-build-web-deployment-web-deploy-vs.html